# Highlighting results with Lucene

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

```
        QueryScorer queryScorer = new QueryScorer(query, "title");
        Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleSpanFragmenter(queryScorer);

        Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(queryScorer); // Set the best scorer fragments
        highlighter.setTextFragmenter(fragmenter); // Set fragment to highlight            

        SearchFactory searchFactory = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory();
        IndexReader indexReader = searchFactory.getIndexReaderAccessor().open(SearchResult.class);        
        indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        // STEP C
        System.out.println("");
        ScoreDoc scoreDocs[] = indexSearcher.search(query, 20).scoreDocs;
        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : scoreDocs) {
            Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
            String title = document.get("title");
            TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("title", new StringReader(title));
             LOG.info(String.format("TEXTE BRUT: %s", title));
             String fragment = highlighter.getBestFragments(tokenStream, title, 3, "...");
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "--------- FRAGMENT search : ", fragment);
```

I have this error where I try to get hightlighted results :

Failed to define class org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.TermVectorLeafReader in Module "deployment.dev-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.VerifyError:

Failed to link org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/TermVectorLeafReader (Module "deployment.scob-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader): class org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.TermVectorLeafReader overrides final method terms.(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/lucene/index/Terms;

Comment: I guess this is on WildFly ? Which version of these libraries? If you provide specific we might be able to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get such a `VerifyError` when using a version of the `Highlighter` not compatible with the expected version of Apache Lucene.

Verify which version of Lucene your app server is using and get a matching version of the Highlighter.

Comment: Right ! It works very well ! I change my lucene from 7.0.0 to 5.5.4 which is suitable for hibernate-search 5.8.0 (in my case). Thanks !